# django permalink error

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

I have a page with some years. I want to click over the year, for instance 2000, to see all the information.
What I have in urls is this:

```
url(r'^browse/time/(\d{4})/$', 'TBDBsite.tb.views.data_time', name="yr"),
```

In models:

```
@permalink  
def get_absolute_url(self):  
return('year', [str(self.date.year)])
```

And in the template:

```
{% for y in yr %}
   <li><a href="{{ y.get_absolute_url }}"><p> {{ y }}</p></a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

When I print {{ yr }} I see a list with the years but the url doesn't work.

Anyone has any idea how to solve this?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your url to

```
url(r'^browse/time/(?P<y>\d{4})/$', 'TBDBsite.tb.views.data_time', name="yr"),
```

then in the template

```
{% for y in yr%}
<a href="{% url yr y%}" >foo</a>
{% endfor %}
```

And that's all

Comment: yes! you're right! Actually I already had made that change in my code, but didn't updated my answer. I was learning and my answer was the best solution at the time. Later on, I rewrote the code :)

Answer (score 0):

In the urlconf you've used the name `yr`, but in the permalink you've used `year`. Use the same name in both places.

Comment: sorry, I've been playing around trying to figure out..
it's changed but doesn't work..

Comment: More information needed, then. What does 'doesn't work' mean? Do you get an error? What is actually output in the HTML source in the href? What are `y` and `yr` in the context?

Comment: Sorry..
I don't get any error but when I try to click on 2000(example) nothing happen, so something is wrong.
yr is a list with all the years. I have the years displayed but not the link..
I'm still new in django, so sorry if it is something silly..

Comment: I've another permalink in the same model, used in different views and with different names. I went to check the other and now it doesn't work, I mean before the link was correct and now in the other view I get what I wanted in this.. Is there another way to distinguish between these two? So that it work